# Convert byte array (ISO FMC format )to bitmap

Tags: android, templates, bitmap

In my code I have a method `grabFingerprint()`;  this method returns a `byte[] array`.
The byte array represents fingerprint data in `ISO FMC COMPACT` format, or null. (ISO_19794_2_2005 )

Now I want to convert this array to a bitmap. But standard conversion causes the application to crash without an error.

```
Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(iso, 0, iso.length);
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated..

Comment: I think you need to set the format in bitmapFactory.Options and pass the options to the decodeByteArray method

Comment: You will probably have to use a library as the Bitmap API doesn't have any way to do this natively

Comment: @pravin Divraniya kindly helpout from this kind of issue i stuck in this problem iso-fmr does not convert into bitmap and return null always

Comment: @Xeeshan Sami please add a new question regarding your problem and elaborate more on that. Also tag me in comment. I will definitely check it and see what I can do in.

Comment: Sure sir why not